# Not able to pass Object over pipeline in C# to run powershell commands

Tags: c#, powershell, command, pipeline

I want to run following PS cmd using C#

```
Get-SCRunAsAccount -VMMServer VmmserverName -Name proName | Remove-SCRunAsAccount
```

I have tried below program but profile is not getting deleted. When i run the above cmd in Powershell it worked, which mean no issue with cmd. but not sure why Object of RunAsAccount is not passing over pipeline in C#.

also i have tried run `Get-process | Sort-Object VM` using pipeline in c# it worked.

help me what i am missing here

```
        Pipeline pipeline = Runspace.CreatePipeline();            
        Collection<PSObject> results = null;
        string output = null;

        Command command = new Command("Get-SCRunAsAccount");            
        command.Parameters.Add("VMMServer", "VmmserverName");
        command.Parameters.Add("Name", "proName");

        Command command1 = new Command("Remove-SCRunAsAccount");

        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(command1);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");          
        results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `SCVMM` cmdlets before you can use them:

```
pipeline.Commands.Add("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name","VirtualMachineManager");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention VMM module are already imported in the runspace.  if i run below it displaying RunasAccount correctly.         Command command = new Command("Get-SCRunAsAccount");            
        command.Parameters.Add("VMMServer", "VmmserverName");
        command.Parameters.Add("Name", "proName");

        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");          
        results = pipeline.Invoke();